# Is it possible to import/export list from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, 2013

We have been using SP 2013 for its ease of use when it comes to developing workflows especially the copy & pasting thing in SPD. But our main production environment will be using SP 2010 for it's relatively faster when it comes to UI interaction based on our experience.

Now our problem would be, is it possible to save the list as template in SP 2013 and then uploading the template in SP2010 at least for the list... Never mind the list workflows... :)

Answer (score 1):

- Navigate to the list on SP2013,go to "Exprot to Excel"
- Open that excel file, and copy(Ctrl-A)
- Navigate  to the list on sp2010,go to "Datasheet View" and paste(Ctrl-V)
- Done......... : )

Comment: I think you're referring to list ITEMS not the list itself. As i've mentioned we're after the list to be saved as template in Sharepoint 2013 and then later on used that template to create a new lists in Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Save list as template in list settings, while doing check include data. Download it from template galleries in site settings. Then upload into 2010 galleries then create the new list using the same template.